# CommandError: Can't find xgettext. with django i18n

Tags: python, django, internationalization

I have building a simple application with django in which I am using `I18N`. But when I tried to run following command,

```
D:\work\i18n\testapp>django-admin.py makemessages -l en
```

I am getting following error ,

```
D:\work\i18n\testapp>django-admin.py makemessages -l en
CommandError: Can't find xgettext. Make sure you have GNU gettext tools 0.15 or
newer installed.
```

After this I have installed [python-gettext](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-gettext) , but I am still getting `CommandError: Can't find xgettext...` error.

Here is my setting.py

```
"""
Django settings for testapp project.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/settings/
"""

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '-rzs11j%&)$=#s)x#bjug(@(7afjaz*wvynfewzaqb_#q1uuez'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

TEMPLATE_DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'testapp.urls'

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'testapp.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'templates'),)


LOCALE_PATHS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'locale'),
)
print(LOCALE_PATHS)
```

Here is my template ,

```
{% load i18n %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 </head>
 <body>
<h3>I18N</h3>
{% trans "Hello" %}
 </body>
</html>
```

What I am missing here ? Any setting or any other module I have to install ?

Comment: Did you download [`gettext` for windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/gettext.htm)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to install `gettext` package.

For windows you can download from [`GetText for Windows`](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/gettext.htm)

If you are using `CentOS` then run the command `yum install gettext`, and for `Ubuntu` users the command is `sudo apt-get install -y gettext`

Comment: The person is using Windows, so your answer does not apply.

Comment: Added link for windows.

Comment: @Lafada Django i18n requires > 0.15 and this link didn't have version 0.15, I have downloaded it from [here](http://mlocati.github.io/gettext-iconv-windows/)

Comment: For OS X and brew: brew install gettext && brew link gettext --force

Comment: this is apparently old port beacuse Execution of msgfmt failed: (null): ...\LC_MESSAGES\django.po:424: keyword "msgctxt" unknown