# CommandError: Can't find xgettext. django

Tags: python, django, internationalization, translation, persian

I am making an app for my website with django and i need to ad persian language to my project. But when I tried to run following command

```
django-admin.py makemessages
```

and i get this error

```
CommandError: Can't find xgettext. Make sure you have GNU gettext tools 0.15 or
```

newer installed.

i have installed python-gettext with pip
and installed [GetText for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/gettext.htm)
and gettext.tools with nuget

i saw some guys with problems similar to mine like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25151858/commanderror-cant-find-xgettext-with-django-i18n) but they're solutions didn't help me
what should i do?
(i am using windows 7 64 bit and i am really noob in django )

Answer (score 0):

Install latest gettext binaries for Windows downloadable [here](http://mlocati.github.io/articles/gettext-iconv-windows.html). Current version is 0.19.8.1.

Shared version should be sufficient. After installation make sure gettext path was added to system paths; `C:\Program Files (x86)\gettext-iconv` or `C:\Program Files (x86)\gettext-iconv`, depending on version.